# Loading Spacemacs init.el post-Aquamacs

Tags: spacemacs, init-file

I have been working with Aquamacs and I would like to take Spacemacs out for a spin. I cloned .spacemacs and created an empty spacemacs file to store my configs later:

```
git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.spacemacs -b develop ~/.spacemacs.d

touch ~/.spacemacs
```

Open up Emacs and try to M-x load-file ~/.spacemacs.d/init.el and I keep running into this:

```
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ~/.emacs.d/core/core-dumper.el
```

I've tried everything I can think of including removing the emacs directory entirely and nothing seems to let me open up Spacemacs. Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't played with Aquamacs in a few years, but here is my 3-step cheat sheet for a generic version of Emacs on OSX:  (1) `git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d/spacemacs`; (2) `(setq spacemacs-start-directory "~/.emacs.d/spacemacs/")`; and (3) `(load-file (concat spacemacs-start-directory "init.el"))`

Comment: Using a generic Emacs for OSX, I also get a loading error, which did not happen a few months ago, after selecting a few of the options such as evil, full / helm, non-minimalistic, etc., I got:  `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Opening directory" "No such file or directory" "/Users/HOME/.emacs.d/.cache/quelpa/melpa/recipes") directory-files("/Users/HOME/.emacs.d/.cache/quelpa/melpa/recipes" nil "^[^.]+")`

Comment: Hey - thanks for getting back with me. Let me try this and we shall see the outcome.

Comment: @lawlist Fantastic! Up and running. Thanks :) You wouldn't happen to know where I can place my org mode customization code so that it'll work with Spacemacs? (If you can't tell, I'm not terribly agile at coding.)

Comment: I do not use spacemacs ... but, I would suggest having a look at the org-mode section of the spacemacs manual and see if anything in there answers your questions:  http://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html

Comment: @lawlist Sorry to keep bugging you, but now when trying to say custom capture templates, they won't save and I get the error "Cannot save customizations, init file not fully loaded" - ever run into this problem?

Comment: That message appears `(when (and (null custom-file) init-file-had-error) ....`  So, your `init-file-had-error` ... Check the `*Messages*` buffer for some clues ... when starting Emacs ... you can also temporarily put `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the beginning of your init file to help you see more detailed debugging messages ....  You may also wish to try commenting out parts of your init file, save, and restart to try and find the error.  Another useful tool is to open the init file and type `M-x check-parens`, which will help you find places you forgot to balance the parentheses ....

Comment: I guess another question I have is how does spacemacs know where to save the customizations? Cause I place (setq debug-on-error t) but I'm not getting any detailed messages.

Comment: I'm wondering at this point if it'd be a good idea to do a refresh on everything. I'm guessing Aquamac mucks with the .emacs file and this might be leading to some of these issues. I'm a little trepidatious about embarking on a total refresh however.

Comment: Inasmuch as I have been unable to install a fresh batch of `spacemacs` since I first made the comment about `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Opening directory" "No such file or directory" "/Users/HOME/.emacs.d/.cache/quelpa/melpa/recipes")
  directory-files("/Users/HOME/.emacs.d/.cache/quelpa/melpa/recipes" nil "^[^.]+")` ... I am not going to much help to you here, sorry.  I also see warnings:  `Warning (spacemacs): Error while contacting melpa repository!
Warning (spacemacs): Error while contacting org repository!
Warning (spacemacs): Error while contacting gnu repository!`.

Comment: You've been a great help - thanks again!